# How to skip "\n" while reading file text

Tags: c++

I have 2 class:

```
Class Student{
private:
    string name;
    string id;
    float mark;
    string address;
public:
    void InPut()
    {
        string Null;
        fflush(stdin);
        getline(cin, name);
        geline(cin, id);
        cin >> mark;
        fflush(stdin);
        getline(cin, Null);
        getline(cin, address);
    }
};

Class ListStudent
{
private:
    Student *list;
    int count;
public:
    void InputList()
    {
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cin >> list[i];
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    freopen("INPUT.txt", "rt", stdin);
    ListStudent list;
    list.InputList();
    return 0;
}
```

And a file text:

```
Christia
15D13
9.8
LA
Jame Bond
15A631
7.2
New York
```

when I read from file text, I have to create a string Null to read "\n" after mark member, and then I read string address to take it. But I don't want to create Null string because I want to input both from keyboard and from file text.
It's so annoying with Null string. How to delete "\n" or read without create a different string?
Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Mixing `std::cin >> something` with `std::getline` is almost always a bad idea. The two don't play nicely (because `>>` doesn't remove trailing `\n`).

Comment: use getline, it's better

Comment: @Hoài Don't post fake code. Make sure the code compiles, copy/paste directly...

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad Ahh, sorry, I'm an idiot.

Comment: Don't use `fflush` with C++ I/O. Replace it with `cin.ignore()`

Answer (score 0):

After you read mark use cin.ignore( ) then getline(cin,address)